# XNA 4.0 - How to render a viewport in a second window

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

I created a 3D World with a top view in XNA. Now i would like to render a viewport (other view than the view of the main window) of this world in a second Window (Winform). Both windows (gamescreen and viewportscreen) should be on the same monitor.

I followed some "XNA in Winforms" Tutorials, but i only had the Init and the Draw method. Is it possible to render a viewport with these methods or is it the wrong way to do this?

Any idea how this could be done?

Thx

btw, i am new to XNA ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.carbonatethis.com/xna-multi-monitor-support/) looks like what you are after.

In summary, the article suggests you create a child class that inherits from GraphicsDeviceManager. This class will essential look for and store connected monitors. You can then create two game windows on separate threads (one for each monitor - remember to replace the GraphicsDeviceManager with your new child class). When instantiating the Game class, pass in the index of the monitor you want to target.

Note that it doesn't use a seperate Winform.

Good luck with your game, and welcome to XNA!

**UPDATE** To have them both on the same monitor (split screen), you can do this by creating 2 new Viewports (e.g., one Viewport for left of screen, another for right of screen). Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313965%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) article on the MSDN.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because they become useless if the page on the other end is moved, edited or deleted. Could you summarise the solution here?

Comment: Hey, i tried this and i think this is very cool. But if it is possible i would like to run both windows (game screen and viewport screen) on one monitor.

Comment: Thanks, but i did this one before :) I see, my question is not clear enough. The viewport should be rendered in an other window so that it can be behind the main window (fullscreen) but not visible to the user. Because i like to stream the viewport onto a tablet (I have already a solution for the streaming but i need a non visible viewport).

Comment: Solved it with the threading of the "multi monitor support" solution. Just on one screen. Thanks